# How to display selected file name when using the Dropbox API JS Chooser

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, dropbox

I am using the dropbox chooser (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) as part of a form. Once the user has selected a file, I would like to display that file name next to the chooser button.

It would also be nice to include a 'remove' link to clear the selection.

i assume that this will be done using javascript/jquery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: An earlier answer used `e.files[0].link.split('/').pop()`, but there's a field for this already! It's called `name`. Updated below.

The file name is one of the things returned, so you can just do this:

```
var url = e.files[0].link;
var name = e.files[0].name;
```

As to how to display it on the page, I would suggest adding a `span` somewhere and setting its text. Try this code, which does that and a couple other nice things (like handle the submit button's disabled state and resetting the Chooser button to its "unused" state):

```
<form>
    <input id="chooser" type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" data-link-type="direct" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
    <p id="chosen" style="display:none">Chosen file: <span id="filename"></span> (<a id="remove" href="#">remove</a>)</p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled />
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#chooser').on('DbxChooserSuccess', function (e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.files[0].link;
            var filename = e.originalEvent.files[0].name;

            $('#chosen').show();
            $('#filename').text(filename);
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        });
        $('#remove').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#chosen').hide();
            $('.dropbox-chooser').removeClass('dropbox-chooser-used');
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I should point out that the `dropbox-chooser-used` class is just something I noticed. Since it's not documented, that may change in a future version of the library. The rest should be fine.