# JSON Post after fetching from Dropbox JavaScript Chooser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, dropbox-api

I'm using the Javascript Dropbox Chooser https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js and with the help of @smarx ([How to display selected file name when using the Dropbox API JS Chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122903/how-to-display-selected-file-name-when-using-the-dropbox-api-js-chooser/20604044#20604044)) I've managed to fetch the `<img src=""` to fetch images into the browser.

The next thing that I want to do is to `POST` those image url's into a `json` file stored on my localhost as: galeria.json via `$.ajax` after the submit button is clicked, however, I can't seem to accomplish it.

I'm relatively new with jQuery and AJAX so I don't understand the error response that I get on my console: Error: [object, Object].

Here's the code:

```
<body>
<form class="gallery-form" action="galeria.json" method="POST">
  <input id="chooser" type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" data-link-type="direct" data-multiselect="true" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
  <div id="chosen" style="display:none"></div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" disabled />
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#chooser').on('DbxChooserSuccess', function (e) {
          for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.files.length; i++) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.files[i].link;
            var filename = e.originalEvent.files[i].name;
            var linkTo = "<img src='" + url + "'" + ">" + "</img>";

            $('#chosen').show();
            $('#chosen').append(linkTo);
          }
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);

            $(".gallery-form").submit(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "galeria.json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {imgUrl: url},
                success: function(response){
                  console.log("Success: " + response.imgUrl);
                },
                error: function(error){
                  console.log("Error: " + error);
                }
              });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

If you would like to help me a little bit more, the goal of doing this is to later `GET` those img url's from the `galeria.json` file into my `index.html` and insert them on a gallery `<section id="gallery">`.

Comment: Change the error method to this one `error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log("Error: ", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ); }` to see more details

Comment: Thanks @czerasz I have this on the console: 
`Error:  
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
 parsererror SyntaxError {}`

Answer (score 0):

What code are you running on the server to receive the JSON request? I suspect you're missing a piece here. Your code to send the URL to the server looks right, but that's not the only step required. On the server, you need some code that's going to receive the request and write the URL to a file.

Comment: Thank you @smarx, do you mean a PHP file or something? Because I only have the json file on the same directory as the index. And the json file has not actual code on it because I expected it to be populated with the ajax POST request.

Comment: Yes, PHP or some other server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store the urls in an array and then submit that to the server. Note that in the AJAX request I'm assuming you have a server that accepts post requests to the resource "/images".

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $('#chooser').on('DbxChooserSuccess', function (e) {
        var urls = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.files.length; i++) {
          var url = e.originalEvent.files[i].link;
          urls.push(url);
          var filename = e.originalEvent.files[i].name;
          var linkTo = "<img src='" + url + "'" + ">" + "</img>";

          $('#chosen').show();
          $('#chosen').append(linkTo);
        }
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);

        $(".gallery-form").submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/images",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {imgUrls: urls},
            success: function(response){
              console.log(response.message);
            },
            error: function(error){
              console.log(error.message);
            }
          });
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

On the server side (Rails in my example since I know you have worked with it) you would process the array. JSON Data sent with an ajax request should be available in the params hash. The params[:imageUrls] would be the array of urls.

```
def create
  params[:imgUrls].each do |url|
    Image.create(path: url)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json {message: 'Success!'} }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, so I should save this Ruby syntax as a ´.rb´ file on the same directory? I guess that Ruby must be installed on my server right?

Comment: Yeah you would need a full back-end server. So run either Sinatra or Ruby on Rails.